# How to contact a potential supervisor when I don't know if I am a good enough candidate?

Tags: phd, advisor, application

I have been following certain mailing lists for PhD opportunities. About a week ago, I found a really interesting position. Unfortunately (?), it is in a top school, so I don't know if my qualifications are enough.

I will finish my master's early next year with decent grades (average is near 4.5 of 5.0). However, my grades in the bachelor's degree are not that good (around 3.0 of 5.0). Anyway, I have several publications, teaching and research experience, and a notable research award. I do not meet desired level of proficiency in one of the sub-components of their preferred english language test (though my average score is higher than what they want).

How would I go about asking more information about the position? I would like to send a brief email but mentioning all of the relevant "positive data" is rather difficult. Should I just ask some specifics, and give a URL to my CV?

What to do here?

(I am aware of the other question asking about how to get bad grades past admission committees. My question here is not the same one. Instead, I would like to know how to make the first contact)

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently looking for a PI to take me as a student ina PhD program. So, I've contacted the student's affair office and they told me to introduce myself to the PI like this:

Hi Professor ABC,
My name is X and I am currently doing BLA BLA BLA at the Z Institute. I am interested in applying for a PhD at BLANK in the area of BLANK and was wondering if you were interested in taking on more students/have room in your lab for me.

---

Simple as that, he will probably ask you for a more detailed profile of yours with your cv.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to provide much information about yourself when asking for more information. I would say something like this:

Subject: Expression of interest in PhD position

Dear Professor X,

My name is X and I am currently doing Y at Z. I am contacting you as I am interested in X and have a few questions in relation to this position that I would appreciate your help with. First, I noticed that you want X skills, is having X-1 acceptable for this?

...

Thank for taking the time to read this.

Kindest Regards,

Y

I would make sure that you only ask the Professor questions you really need to know, and that he alone can answer. Some of the questions you have might be best suited for the admissions office or some other university body. Also keep the email as short as possible, as academics are very busy so they are less likely to answer long emails. Make sure that it is well written and has no typos.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you send someone your CV (or a link to it), a cover letter should accompany it.  Your cover letter should be one to three paragraphs, and should be tailored to the specifics of the position.  You'll need to read up on that department (and the relevant professors), so you can say something relevant to their work.  You don't need to pretend you know a lot about their field; but you should say something personal to help the reader understand why you are interested in working there.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar position, I contacted the program coordinator who had put out the call. I told them I was interested and described my preparation in a bare-bones way, they got back to me a couple days later and asked for specifics to discuss with faculty in the program, I responded, and eventually I got a very polite note that I wouldn't be ready to do well in the program at this time but please keep our institution in mind for the future.

So to echo previous comments, keep it simple. I think it's good to consider it as a conversation at this stage, and you wouldn't try to open a conversation with everything at once.